Error 13 after moving MySQL datadir outside /var/lib, no error when staying inside /var/lib
Recently I installed MySQL, version 8.4.3, on my Ubuntu 22.04.5 OS.
I then changed the datadir from /var/lib/mysql to new location /media/cat/hekla/mysql,
following the approach described in Ergest Basha's answer to the question
Error after changing/moving mysql datadir in ubuntu sys.
Restarting MySQL however fails, and systemctl status mysql.service tells me:
 × mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-11-06 11:18:27 CET; 2min 31s ago
    Docs: man:mysqld(8)
          http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
 Process: 11628 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.4/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 11667 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 11667 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Status: "Server shutdown complete (with return value = 1)"
   Error: 13 (Permission denied)
     CPU: 292ms

nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.019616Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.3) starting as process 11667
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021198Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /media/cat/hekla/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021202Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /media/cat/hekla/mysql/ is case insensitive
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021216Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/media/cat/hekla/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021275Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021685Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.4.3)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
nov 06 11:18:27 golem mysqld[11667]: 2024-11-06T10:18:27.021689Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
nov 06 11:18:27 golem systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov 06 11:18:27 golem systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nov 06 11:18:27 golem systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Interestingly, I made a backup copy /var/lib/mysql.bak of /var/lib/mysql, and when I change the datadir to this backup directory then it does work!
Any ideas what the problem can be, and how to solve it?
Any other things that could require adjustment, perhaps involving location /var/lib/ considering that the backup directory sitting next to the original does work?
The content of /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld is:
include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
 #include <abstractions/base>
 #include <abstractions/nameservice>
 #include <abstractions/user-tmp>
 #include <abstractions/mysql>
 #include <abstractions/winbind>

 # Allow system resource access
  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/** r,
  /proc/*/status r,
  capability sys_resource,
  capability dac_override,
  capability setuid,
  capability setgid,
  capability sys_nice,

 # Allow network access
  network tcp,

 /etc/hosts.allow r,
 /etc/hosts.deny r,

# Allow config access
 /etc/mysql/** r,

# Allow pid, socket, socket lock and other file access
 /run/mysqld/* rw,
 /var/run/mysqld/* rw,

# Allow systemd notify messages
 /{,var/}run/systemd/notify w,

# Allow execution of server binary
 /usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
 /usr/sbin/mysqld-debug mr,

# Allow plugin access
 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ r,
 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/*.so* mr,

# Allow error msg and charset access
 /usr/share/mysql/ r,
 /usr/share/mysql/** r,
 /usr/share/mysql-8.4/ r,
 /usr/share/mysql-8.4/** r,

# Allow data dir access
 /var/lib/mysql/ r,
 /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
#  /var/lib/mysql.bak/ r,
#  /var/lib/mysql.bak/** rwk,
#  /media/cat/hekla/mysql/ r,
#  /media/cat/hekla/mysql/** rwk,

# Allow data files dir access
 /var/lib/mysql-files/ r,
 /var/lib/mysql-files/** rwk,

# Allow keyring dir access
 /var/lib/mysql-keyring/ r,
 /var/lib/mysql-keyring/** rwk,

# Allow log file access
 /var/log/mysql/ r,
 /var/log/mysql/** rw,

# Allow access to openssl config
 /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf r,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.mysqld>
}


# Allow data dir access should be  the new directory not the old one

@ErgestBasha Yes, I had set it to the new one (and also in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf), but when that gave the error I commented it out and reset it to the old one which is what you see here.

Things to check:

Who is the owner of these directories?
What are permissions on these directories?

Both can be obtained by running ls -ld on them.
Personally, I recommend also using ls -ldn because Unix permissions revolve around uids (and gids) and not around usernames and I've worked in places where they do "strange things" with usernames and uids!
Remember, the database does not run under your account.
Just because you can see / update these directories doesn't mean that your database process can!

Thanks! Running ls -ldn yields drwxr-x--- 9 129 138 for the original directory /var/lib/mysql/ and its backup /var/lib/mysql.bak/ (both yield no error as datadir) and for the preferred location /media/cat/hekla/mysql/ (which does yield an error as datadir). So I suppose that means that ownership and permissions of the datadir are not the issue, right?

@Bart 129 138 should be user and group , run cat /etc/passwd and see user, group for 129 138. Do you have apparmor active ? What's the content of /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ?

@ErgestBasha user 129 and group 138 both are mysql. When changing the datadir I ran systemctl restart apparmor.service so I suppose it's active. I'll include the content of /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld above.

So I managed to make it work.
In an answer on Stack Overflow
it was said that all parent directories of my new datadir
/media/cat/hekla/mysql
should have x (execute) permissions, which wasn't the case yet:
it was for
drwxr-xr-x  9 cat cat  4096 nov 15 16:08 hekla
and
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 jun  6  2022 media
but not for
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 4096 nov 15 16:03 cat
By applying sudo chmod o+x cat/ I changed that to
drwxr-x--x+ 4 root root 4096 nov 15 16:03 cat
This as an extra step just before restarting apparmor and MySQL, no error now.
